# How to calculate Recursion runtime (java)

Tags: java, time-complexity, runtime

i have this function that print numbers from Binary tree
if the numbers in range [a,b]

```
public void print_in_range(Node root,int a, int b){ // print all num in [a,b] --> (a < b) 
    if(root == null)
        return;
        
    if(root.value >= a  && root.value <= b)
        System.out.print(root.value + ",");
    
        print_in_range(root.left, a, b);
        print_in_range(root.right, a, b); 
}
```

1. What is the runtime of the function?
2. what will be the formula of the function?

For example:

T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n --> T(n) = O(n)

Comment: But he asks about specific problems \ function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use the master theorem to calculate the run time complexity of this particular function. you can find the theorem here [Complexity of recursive algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/)

Comment: yes, i know how to use the master theorem, but i dont know how  to  build  the formula  for this function. I think it is T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(1) But I'm not sure

Comment: I think this would be T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1), note that O(1) is same as O(n^0) so master theorem still applies. It is n/2 because for each iteration you will cut the tree in half (right and left) and it has a constant function "O(1)" because you are nly printing there is no calculations